# ThreeJS First person camera 'resets' when moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm trying to make a first-person camera using [this pointer lock control](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/examples/js/PointerLockControls.js), used by [this cannon.js (physics) demo](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/examples/threejs_voxel_fps.html). However, when I was trying the demo, I noticed that if I move my mouse at a regular speed (or fast), it keeps 'going back', rotating the camera suddenly to a previous position. It doesn't allow looking around freely. It looks like when the (invisible) mouse reached an edge, it would teleport to the opposite one, therefore rotating the camera accordingly.
The same happens in [this official three.js demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock).

This happens in Google Chrome, but not in Edge. Why? How can I prevent that problem in Chrome?

[image]

Comment: I just tried the threejs demo, and everything is working well on my side. What version of google chrome are you running? Are you using a trackpad or a physical mouse?

Comment: Weird. I'm using Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (latest right now), as well as a physical mouse.

Comment: Ok this is strange. I am using the same version, and both examples work well...